# Torah Hebrew calligraphy

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, sefer-torah, safrus

I want to know what was the calligraphy used in the first Torah manuscript? I searched Google but found no answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a famous dispute in the Gemara. According to Mar Zutra (and some say Mar Ukva), the Torah was originally given in Ktav Ivri. According to Rebbi and Rabbi Shimon ben Eliezer (in the name of Rabbi Eliezer ben Perata, in the name of Rabbi Elazar HaModa'i) the Torah was originally given in Ktav Ashurit. ([Comparison photo](https://w3.chabad.org/media/images/1000/imkR10002789.jpg)) See Sanhedrin [21b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=21b&format=pdf) through [22a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=22&format=pdf) for more on this. (In any case, the halacha is that a Sefer Torah must be written in Ktav Ashurit.)